# Compute for the income tax to be paid based on the given salary

Tags: c

Write a program that asks for the salary of an employee, and computes for the income tax to be paid based on the given salary. Use the following scheme for tax computation:

2% for the first 1000 pesos
7% for the next 2000 pesos
11% for the remaining value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float salary, incometax;

    printf("Enter salary: ");
    scanf("%f", &salary);

    if (salary <= 1000)
    {
       incometax = salary * 0.02;
       printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2f\n", incometax);
    }
     else if (salary <= 2000)
    {
       incometax = salary * 0.07;
       printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2f\n", incometax);
    }
    else if (salary > 2000)
    {
       incometax = salary * 0.11;
       printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2f\n", incometax);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

i dont know if what im doing is correct

// update

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float salary, incometax;

    printf("Enter salary: ");
    scanf("%f", &salary);

    if (salary <= 1000)
    {
        incometax = salary * 0.02;
        printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2f Pesos\n", incometax);
    }
    else if (salary < 3000)
    {
        incometax = (salary - 1000) * 0.07 + (1000 * 0.2);
        printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2f Pesos\n", incometax);
    }
    else 
    {
        incometax = ((salary - 3000) * 0.11) + 2000 * 0.07 + 1000 * 0.02;
        printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2f Pesos\n", incometax);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i believe its something like this. I dont if my conditions are correct though. please check. welp

Comment: Well, you should tell us what the problem is  for example with actual output and expected output.  For example what should the tax be for 4000 pesos?  I don't think your problem is a correct translation of the tax rules.

Comment: Money is usually fixed point but if you want to use a floating point type prefer double to float.

Comment: Note that it is a very bad idea to mix integer constants and floating point constants in the same expression. You are also using `float` variables but `double` constants, which doesn't make sense. Most likely you should just use `double`, `%lf` and `0.0` formatting everywhere (that's how you program C on a PC anyway).

Comment: @Lundin Why is it bad idea to mix integer and floating point constants?  I can't think of any ill effects of automatic type conversion here.

Comment: @AllanWind In the code posted, there are numerous implicit promotions and then an implicit conversion back to `float`, which comes with a loss of precision. We shouldn't allow implicit promotions to happen at a whim - good code doesn't contain any at all. Addtionally there's them classic newbie bugs like `5/2 + 0.5` or `double x = 5/2;`.

Comment: It's a great idea to revise your question with clarifications and data reflects so it reflects the best way to are able to communicate it.  Don't try to revise it with an answer, though.  Review of working code is off-top.  Previous versions of your question are available if anyone wants to look at them.

Comment: @Lundin As an aside I got along well with Ada which required explicit type conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your program does not implement marginal tax rules correctly.  For example, with salary of 4000 pesos your program says the income tax is 0.11 * 4000 = 440 but it should be 0.02 * 1000 + 0.07 * 2000 + 0.11 * 1000 = 270.

Here is one implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double incometax(double salary) {
    double incometax = 0;
    if(salary < 0)
        incometax += 0;
    else if(salary <= 1000)
        incometax += 0.02 * (salary - 0);
    else
        incometax += 0.02 * (  1000 - 0);

    if(salary < 1000)
        incometax += 0;
    else if(salary <= 3000)
        incometax += 0.07 * (salary - 1000);
    else
        incometax += 0.07 * (  3000 - 1000);

    if(salary < 3000)
        incometax += 0;
    else
        incometax += 0.11 * (salary - 3000);
    return incometax;
}

int main(void) {
    double salary;
    printf("Enter salary: ");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);
    printf("Income tax to be paid: %.2lf\n", incometax(salary));
}
```

or more concisely with the tertiary operator (`?:`):

```
double incometax(double salary) {
    return
        0.02 * (salary <=    0 ? 0 : (salary <= 1000) ? salary -    0 : 1000 -    0) +
        0.07 * (salary <= 1000 ? 0 : (salary <= 3000) ? salary - 1000 : 3000 - 1000) +
        0.11 * (salary <= 3000 ? 0 : salary - 3000);
}
```

Tax rules are subject to change so it's better express them as data (possible read from an external source like a file, database or website).  You may also have noticed when studying the above two solutions that they repeat the same thing for each of the 3 rules. This implies using a loop.  Finally, observe that maximum marginal salary for rule `i` is the same as the minimum marginal salary for rule `i+1`:

```
#include <values.h> // MAXDOUBLE

double incometax(double salary) {
    static const struct {
        double min;
        double rate;
    } rules[] = {
        {0, 0.02},
        {1000, 0.07},
        {3000, 0.11},
        {MAXDOUBLE, 0}
    };
    const size_t n = sizeof rules / sizeof *rules;
    double incometax = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        incometax += rules[i].rate * (
            salary <= rules[i].min ? 0 :
            salary <= rules[i+1].min ? salary - rules[i].min :
            rules[i+1].min - rules[i].min
        );
    return incometax;
}
```

Comment: My pleasure. If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elaborate program with the following features:

- Accepts income of up to ca. 1.8 * 10<sup>13</sup> units (Rupees, Dollars etc).
- Computes cent-exact.
- Accepts data from the command line or stdin.
- Prompts when stdin is a terminal.
- Handles input errors.
- Even on a terminal one can simply paste space multiple separated numbers,
  no need to have one per line (6th input prompt below).

Maybe some things apart from the actual algorithm are useful here:

- Use a return type which can communicate errors (`struct ParseResult`).
- Use the return value of `scanf` and other input functions to detect input errors, and distinguish it from end-of-file.
- Move similar-looking code into parametrized functions instead of duplicating it (`MakeParseResult()` makes `ParseIncomeInHundredthsFromString()` and `ParseIncomeInHundredthsFromStream()` both small).
- Some algorithms are well-suited for recursion, like this one (`computeTaxes()`).
- Separate input from processing (`computeTaxes()` knows nothing about I/O).
- Like in Allan's answer, do not hard-wire data in the code (the `taxSteps` array could be read from somewhere).
- Pay attention to value ranges (32 bits are not enough for big incomes, let alone in cent or Rupees).
- Use the proper conversion specifiers in `printf()` and `scanf()`, here: `PRIu64` and `SCNu64`. It's somewhat cumbersome but necessary for portability. Different implementations have different native data types for the `uint.._t` typedefs, and thus need different conversion specifiers (what's `%ul` on Linux is `%ull` on Windows, for example).
- Even though it is not standard C, some common Posix functions like `isatty()` are available in non-Posix implementations as well. They are useful.

Sample sessions:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o income-tax income-tax.c && ./income-tax.exe
Tax brackets:
0.00 .. 1000.00: 2.00%
1000.00 .. 3000.00: 7.00%
Above: 11.00%
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
1000.00
Taxes for 1000.00: 20.00
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
3000.00
Taxes for 3000.00: 160.00
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
10000.00
Taxes for 10000.00: 930.00
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
10000.10
Taxes for 10000.10: 930.01
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
1234.56 7890.89 121212121212.12
Taxes for 1234.56: 36.41
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
Taxes for 7890.89: 697.99
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
Taxes for 121212121212.12: 13333333163.33
Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'
$
```

From command line and per pipe:

```
$ ./income-tax.exe 1500.00 4500.25 1234567890123.00
Taxes for 1500.00: 55.00
Taxes for 4500.25: 325.02
Taxes for 1234567890123.00: 135802467743.53
$ echo "1500.00 4500.25 1234567890123.00" | ./income-tax.exe
Taxes for 1500.00: 55.00
Taxes for 4500.25: 325.02
Taxes for 1234567890123.00: 135802467743.53
```

```
//*************************************************
// A tax computing program for a multi-step tax bracket.
// The brackets are specified in the taxSteps array.
// The program is currency agnostic but assumes a 
// "unit" and "hundredths" (Dollar/Cent, Euro/Cent, Pound/Penny).
// It stores money values in those "hundredths" (e.g. Cents) 
// using 64 bit integers. (32 bit would not quite be enough
// for the highest earners; Elon Musk payed $11bn in 2021.)
// The tax rate is likewise stored in 1/100s of a percent
// to facilitate non-integer tax rates.
// All arithmetics are integer; resulting taxes are rounded down.
//
// The program accepts input as commandline arguments 
// ("income-tax 1234.56 777.88") or from standard input
// ("echo 1234.56 777.88 | income-tax").
// Iff standard input is a terminal it issues a prompt.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // for 64 bit type
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h> // uint64_max
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#ifdef _MSC_VER // microsoft compiler, as opposed to *nix environment
#   define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // silence MSVC
#   pragma warning(disable : 4996) // MSVC prefers _isatty
#   include<io.h>
#else
#   include <unistd.h>
#endif

// Convenience function because of the unwieldy format strings.
// Prints "a string like "123.45" from 12345.
void printHundredths(uint64_t Hundredths)
{
    printf("%" PRIu64 ".%02" PRIu64, Hundredths / 100, Hundredths % 100);
}

/// A single tax step: An interval in centi-money units with a rate in "centipercent".
struct TaxStep
{
    uint64_t StepSizeInHundredths;
    unsigned int TaxRateInHundredthPercent;
};

uint64_t computeTaxesInHundredthsForStep(uint64_t incomeInHundredths, struct TaxStep taxStep)
{ 
    uint64_t taxedInThisStep 
        = incomeInHundredths < taxStep.StepSizeInHundredths 
        ? incomeInHundredths 
        : taxStep.StepSizeInHundredths;
    
    // Such a high income would overflow in the expression below and compute 
    // a tax amount that's much too low. The threshold, for 100% tax, is 
    // > 1.8E15 Hundredths, or 1.8E13 whatever (dollars, rupees). In rupees
    // we get close to a realistic income (one rupee ~ 1 cent), 1.8E12, 
    // 1.8 trillion dollars. If, say, Elon Musk liquidates its entire
    // stock at the zenith of his wealth, in Rupees or Lira, we could come close. 
    // Let's say that's OK for now.
    if (    taxStep.TaxRateInHundredthPercent != 0
        &&  taxedInThisStep > UINT64_MAX / taxStep.TaxRateInHundredthPercent)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Income ");
        printHundredths(incomeInHundredths);
        fprintf(stderr, " exceeds value range.\nMax permissible : ");
        printHundredths(UINT64_MAX / taxStep.TaxRateInHundredthPercent);
        exit(2);
    }

    // taxableMoney * HundredthsPercent is precise 
    // (and won't overflow, we asserted that above).
    // The division is exact to the cent, rounded down (we are a nice tax office).
    // The rate is in "centipercent", so we must then divide by 100*100.
    // With percent: "money*11/100" with "centipercent": "money*1100/10000".
    return (taxedInThisStep * taxStep.TaxRateInHundredthPercent) / 10000;
}

/// <summary>
/// Step through the tax bracket and apply the tax rate to each
/// step. The steps are interval sizes, not absolute values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="incomeInHundredth">The income in cents or whatever</param>
/// <param name="taxSteps">The first element in an array of tax steps which have
/// an interval size and a rate for that interval.</param>
/// <returns></returns>

uint64_t computeTaxes(uint64_t incomeInHundredth, struct TaxStep* taxSteps)
{
    // The function simply calls itself with the remaining money
    // and the remaining tax brackets. Because the last interval is
    // UINT_MAX, incomeInHundredth <= taxSteps->StepSizeInHundredths
    // always triggers for the last interval, stopping the recursion.
    return computeTaxesInHundredthsForStep(incomeInHundredth, *taxSteps)
        + (   incomeInHundredth <= taxSteps->StepSizeInHundredths 
            ? 0 
            : computeTaxes(incomeInHundredth - taxSteps->StepSizeInHundredths, taxSteps+1)
          );
}

// A convenience function.
void errExit(const char* msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, msg);
    exit(1); // indicates error
}

/// <summary>
/// Communicates the result of a parsing attempt. EOI is "end of information".
/// </summary>
enum ParseDiagE { ParseDiag_ERR, ParseDiag_EOI, ParseDiag_OK };

/// <summary>
/// A 64 return value which also carries an indicator whether
/// the value could be set properly from the input.
/// </summary>
struct ParseResult
{
    uint64_t parsedValue;
    enum ParseDiagE parseDiag;
};

/// <summary>
/// Factored out the common logic of the two parse methods below.
/// Sets the ret.parseDiag member appropriately, depending on the scanf diagnostic
/// return value (which indicates the number of parsed items and should be 2).
/// If the diag value is OK, combines the two numbers before and after the dot
/// to set ret.parsedValue,
/// </summary>
/// <returns>the result structure</returns>
struct ParseResult MakeParseResult(uint64_t incomeInInUnits, uint64_t IncomeFractionInHundredths, int scanfDiag)
{
    struct ParseResult ret = { 0, ParseDiag_OK };
    switch (scanfDiag)
    {
    case EOF:
        // typically OK: End of string, or end of file/pipe closed.
        ret.parseDiag = ParseDiag_EOI;
        break;
    case 0:
    case 1:
        // bad input: scanf should have read 2.
        ret.parseDiag = ParseDiag_ERR;
        break;
    }
    if (IncomeFractionInHundredths > 99)
    {
        // Could be parsed, but too many "cents", e.g. 1.234
        ret.parseDiag = ParseDiag_ERR;
    }

    if (ret.parseDiag == ParseDiag_OK)
    {
        // only if everything is OK, actually compute anything.
        ret.parsedValue = incomeInInUnits * 100 + IncomeFractionInHundredths;
    }
    return ret;
}

/// <summary>
/// Expects a number in the English float format [0-9]+\.[0-9]+
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
struct ParseResult ParseIncomeInHundredthsFromString(const char* input)
{
    uint64_t incomeInInUnits = 0, IncomeFractionInHundredths = 0;

    int diag = sscanf(input, "%" SCNu64 ".%" SCNu64, &incomeInInUnits, &IncomeFractionInHundredths);
    return MakeParseResult(incomeInInUnits, IncomeFractionInHundredths, diag);
}

/// <summary>
/// Expects a number in the English float format [0-9]+\.[0-9]+
/// Output a prompt only if asked (do not spam sdout for batch runs).
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
struct ParseResult ParseIncomeInHundredthsFromStream(FILE *stream, int prompt)
{
    if (prompt)
    {
        printf("Please input income values in a format like '12345.99 ...'\n");
    }
    uint64_t incomeInInUnits = 0, IncomeFractionInHundredths = 0;

    int diag = fscanf(stream, "%" SCNu64 ".%" SCNu64, &incomeInInUnits, &IncomeFractionInHundredths);
    return MakeParseResult(incomeInInUnits, IncomeFractionInHundredths, diag);
}

void PrintTaxBrackets(struct TaxStep *steps)
{
    uint64_t overallIncomeInHundredths = 0;
    printf("Tax brackets:\n");
    while(1)
    {
        if (steps->StepSizeInHundredths == UINT64_MAX)
        { 
            printf("Above: ");
            printHundredths(steps->TaxRateInHundredthPercent);
            printf("%%\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printHundredths(overallIncomeInHundredths);
            printf(" .. ");
            printHundredths(overallIncomeInHundredths += steps->StepSizeInHundredths);
            printf(": ");
            printHundredths(steps->TaxRateInHundredthPercent);
            printf("%%\n");
            ++steps;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // The specification of the tax brackets: A succession of intervals
    // with their respective tax rate, in "centipercent" (1120 would be 11.20%).
    // The last step **must** be of size UINT64_MAX (i.e., the remaining income),
    // that's how the program recognizes it's the last step
    struct TaxStep taxSteps[] = { {1000 * 100, 2 * 100}, {2000 * 100, 7 * 100}, {UINT64_MAX, 11 * 100 } };

    // If we have command line arguments we should process those.
    int ShouldProcessArgv = argc > 1;

    // If stdin is a terminal
    int inpIsFromTerminal = isatty(fileno(stdin));

    // spam stdout only for interactive sessions.
    if (!ShouldProcessArgv && inpIsFromTerminal)
    {
        PrintTaxBrackets(taxSteps);
    }

    /// Command line argument index. argv[0] is the program name,
    /// so we start with index 1 for the first actual argument.
    int argi = 1; 
    
    // loop through text command line arguments or textual numbers
    // from stdin.
    do
    {
        // Iff there are no command line arguments, we check standard input.
        // Apart from the input source, the processing is the same.
        struct ParseResult res = ShouldProcessArgv
            ? ParseIncomeInHundredthsFromString(argv[argi])
            : ParseIncomeInHundredthsFromStream(stdin, inpIsFromTerminal);

        if (res.parseDiag == ParseDiag_ERR)
        {
            errExit("Input format error\n");
        }
        else if (res.parseDiag == ParseDiag_EOI)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("Taxes for ");
        printHundredths(res.parsedValue);
        printf(": ");
        printHundredths(computeTaxes(res.parsedValue, taxSteps));
        printf("\n");
    } while (ShouldProcessArgv ? ++argi < argc : 1);
    return 0;
}
```